# External SSD is not showing up as bootable device in BIOS

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, asus-laptop, usb-c

So I recently bought an external SSD with USB-C. I tried a few tools to burn Linux on this SSD and make it bootable. But apparently in my Boot Menu of my Asus [Zenphyrus GX501VIK](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/GX501VIK/0409_E12726_GX501VIK_A.pdf) it is not showing up as boot  device. I already turned off fast-boot and secure-boot. I already can see my current boot device twice. Once with Windows and one without a working boot system, but apparently my new device is not showing up there.

Important notes:
I used Rufus to make my SSD bootable. 
I connected it directly from USB-C to USB-C.
I am using Windows 10 as my main system.
I used the Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS iso file

Computer system:

Model: GX501VIK
Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
System type: x64

If you need more information, just ask me. I will try to provide it.
Would be nice if someone can help me to find a solution :)

Comment: Some older PC's cannot boot from an external SSD because such device is not recognized in the firmware. But see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057326/external-ubuntu-ssd-not-recognized-by-windows-10-pc and https://superuser.com/questions/835036/how-to-use-ssd-as-external-drive-and-get-the-good-performance

Comment: @K7AAY I don't know why you need the name, but why I added all the information you need. Thanks for your effort so far!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik This Laptop was pretty new as I bought it 2 years ago so I don't think thats the case, but thanks for the advice! :)